# Field update workflow not updating field value

Tags: workflow, account, field-update

There is an object called CustomerOfTheWeek.

It has a lookup field called Account.

There is another field called Account Type, which is a field update (+ workflow rule) which for the purpose of this question assume it's just the Account Type from the Account. (In reality it simplifies the account types in the Account object to a more generic set of values).

The field update gets triggered when something on the CustomerOfTheWeek changes.

The issue is that if the Account Type changes, the Account Type field in the CustomerOfTheWeek doesn't get changed. (which makes sense but that is not what the client expects).

So a mere edit and save on the CustomerOfTheWeek is now required to trigger the Account Type change.

Is there any way to trigger the change in Account Type in Account object to cause a trigger on the Account Type in CustomerOfTheWeek object?

Comment: should the two fields have the same values? If yes, why not a formula field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of using a formula field, which would probably work in most cases, you can use a Process Builder on the Account to update the Customer of the Week record. The Process Builder has an option to update child records related to a parent record.